# FullText Seach Using Parse Dashboard API match exact case

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, angular7, parse-dashboard

Hi I have an application in angular 7 using Parse Dashboard to handle database. I am building a search algorithm which will search specific words with given input.
However i want to match exact case of given input.

For Example if i search - telecom networks it should give results only for telecom networks not telecom alone or networks alone.

Here is the Code

```
  let s = '"'
  term.forEach(x => {
    s = s + '\"'
    s = s + x + '\" '
  })
  s = s.slice(0, -1);
  s = s + '"'
  if (s != '') {
    query.fullText('data', s, {diacriticSensitive: true});
  }
```

term is an array of strings from user input
using query.fullText() i am getting response of networks alone also but i have to exclude it. i have searched everywhere but not solution is found.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: telecom and network should be together or irrespective of their position you need result?

Comment: @KuldeepDubey "Telecom Network" exact should exist in the Data anywhere. I mean if i give a sentence it should exist in the Data and give results for That.

Comment: can u append the string and then do a single search. eg. arr[0]='a' and arr[1]='b' then append and create it as "a b". Search "a b". Are you looking something like this?